# I found a skeleton horse that had spawned(No lightning/storm), and I tried to ride/tame it and it doesn't do anything

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

So I got on my mc windows 10 edition survival world and I found a skeleton horse that had spawned for whatever reason(No lightning/storm), and I tried to ride/tame it and it doesn't do anything. I don't even know why it spawned, I didn't use cheats or anything either. It did however spawn in my nether portal room so it could of possibly came out of the nether?

Comment: Your horse should have gone into the nether through a portal from the overworld, not spawned in the nether.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to understand the mechanics of the skeleton horse, they can spawn by themselves, or they can spawn when a regular horse is struck by lightning.
Now you can't ride one unless it's been ridden by a skeleton in the past. A way to tell is walk up to a skeleton horse during a thunderstorm, and once you get close enough it should get struck again this time spawn more skeleton horse with skeletons ridding them. Kill the skeletons, and then you can equip the horse with a saddle and ride them. However, you can't equip it with horse armor.
Hope this helps!!